# How to Sort data in dataset using dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, webforms, dataset

I am using asp.net webforms application and listing products on page load. I want to sort data when i am selecting a value from dropdownlist. If i use `static DataSet` i can sort data using dropdownlist but it's not useful when you have visitors more then one.

I don't want to use Session variable for sorting products. What's the alternative to sorting data using dropdownlist? I am listing products on the page, just want to sort. When i click on the dropdown list for sorting, DataSet returns "null" But i can see products on the page in repeater. It doesn't disappear.

Dropdown listing code:

```
protected DataSet data {get;set;}

protected void dropdown_sort_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(data != null)
   {
     ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = "product_id asc"
   }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we assume then a drop down list to select the column to sort, and then say a gridview.

So, say this markup:

```
Sort Data by:
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="120px"
    AutoPostBack="true" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" Width="40%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"     />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"       />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"     />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"               />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Ok, code to load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadCombo();
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    void LoadCombo()
    {
        string OrderList = "Select Order,HotelName,City,FirstName,LastName";

        foreach (string sOrder in OrderList.Split(','))
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(sOrder);
        }
    }

    void LoadGrid(string OrderBy = "")
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA";
        if ( (OrderBy != "") & (OrderBy != "Select Order") )
            strSQL += " ORDER BY " + OrderBy;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {

                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And we now have this:

[image]

Now, code for the drop down list (note the autopostback=true).

We have this code:

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid(DropDownList1.Text);
    }
```

So, say we select this from the drop down:

[image]

We now see this:

[image]